# Combining VLOOKUP, OR, AND IF Statements in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Trying to write a statement with a combination of VLOOKUP, OR, and IF. Struggling with the placement of IF and OR clauses and/or parentheses.

Here's what I've tried:

```
IF(OR(VLOOKUP(B4,Agreements!F:G,2,0),VLOOKUP(C4,Agreements!F:G,2,0)) = "Active", "Yes", "No")
```

(Returns #N/A)

```
=IF(OR(VLOOKUP(B4,Agreements!F:G,2,0)="Active","Yes","No",VLOOKUP(C4,Agreements!F:G,2,0))="Active","Yes","No")
```

(Returns No when it should return Yes)

Comment: `OR(VLOOKUP(B4,Agreements!F:G,2,0)={"Active","Yes","No"},VLOOKUP(C4,Agreements!F:G,2,0))={"Active","Yes","No"})`

Comment: Unless you want the returns to be `Yes`, `No`.  Then: `=IF(OR(VLOOKUP(B4,Agreements!F:G,2,0)="Active",VLOOKUP(C4,Agreements!F:G,2,0)="Active"),"Yes","No")`

Comment: @ScottCraner - doesn't that formula need to handle error(s)?

Comment: @BigBen :P `=IF(OR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B4,Agreements!F:G,2,0),"")="Active",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C4,Agreements!F:G,2,0),"")="Active"),"Yes","No")`

Comment: I actually think, since B4 and C4 are contiguous, you can do: `=IF(OR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B4:C4,Agreements!F:G,2,0),"")="Active"),"Yes","No")` It may take ctrl-shift-enter in older version, I do not have access anymore to older versions to test.